# Will This Session Cookie Method Slow Down My Site Performance

Tags: php, session, cookies, authentication, mybb

I am making a feature for my site now the only issue I want it to be compatible for any forum system with only minor edits needed in case I do decide to move or if the Mybb software (which I currently use) updates and breaks something so I am also preventing this.

Anyway instead of using the default Mybb Username system I have decided to detect if a user is logged in then when they visit a feature for the site on first load (since $_COOKIE requires two loads to become in affect) 
start a session then on the second load destroy the session and translate it in to a cookie

here's what I have currently have (no where a near fully written)

```
//if the user is logged in assign a session
if($mybb->user['username']) {
  session_start();
$mybb_username1 = $mybb->user['username'];

$_SESSION['user']=$mybb_username1;
$mybb_username = $_SESSION['user'];
}
```

Do any of you's have a better method or is this fine?

Just making sure.

i'm also want this to be secure and not slow down any performance of the overall site functionality.

Thanks!

Comment: What is the point behind `$x = $y, $z = $x, $w = $z` ? `Just write $x = $z = $w = $y`.

Comment: Sessions are implemented with cookies (to store the correct session id) so i dont know what you are trying to acheive

Comment: the only issue with sessions is once the user closes there browser it gone and a cookie needs two refreshes to fully set. 
@ClémentMalet what do you mean?

Comment: @TheMajorNerd If you need two refreshes to use your cookies, then you're doing something wrong. It shouldn't be needed. (My first comment was just about how you're using 3 unclear lines to affect your variables instead of a single and clear one as I suggested)

Comment: from what I read up it's normal as a cookie needs to be sent to the server and set by the server first then it can be used on a secound reload and I agree with you there this is just testing code to get something working

Comment: would it be better that every time the user closes there browser it will just reset the session would that slow down performace?